# Multiple WP_Query args combinations according to post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, meta-query

I'd like to have separate `meta_query` arguments according to the post type.

For example, I'd like to query `t-shirts` that have a *green collar* or `dress-shirts` that have a *green inner-lining*, right now I only do a single post type check where I check for `t-shirts` *and* `dress-shirts` and I separately check for the meta values which mean that it will also show different combinations such as `t-shirts` that have a *green inner-lining*

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('t-shirts', 'dress-shirts'),
    'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'key' => 'collar',
        'value' => 'green',
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'inner-lining',
        'value' => 'green',
      )
    ),
));
```

How can I set it up to work with two different args, one if the post type is `t-shirts` and a seperate args if the post type is `dress-shirts` which would look something like:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
  array(
    array(
      'post_type' => array('t-shirts'),
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'heal',
          'value' => 'green',
        )
      ),
    ),
    array(
      'post_type' => array('dress-shirts'),
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'sleeve',
          'value' => 'green',
        )
      ),
    ),
  )
);
```

Doing two separate queries won't work as it will mess up pagination.

---

*Please note this is a copy of the same question on [wp.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/373269/multiple-wp-query-args-combinations-according-to-post-type) as there is little-to-no activity there.*

Comment: why you dont want to go with 1st approach ? issues ?

Comment: @PrinceSingh This will also return t-shirts that have the `sleeve = green` meta field - I only want to see dress-shirts that have a green sleeve OR t-shirts that have the `collar = green` meta field

Comment: this might not be possible with WP_Query, you will have to build a custom query.

Answer (score 0):

WP_Query does not accept this parameter format. you can try this below code

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => array( 't-shirts', 'dress-shirts'),
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'heal',
                'value' => 'green',
            ),
            array(
              'key' => 'sleeve',
              'value' => 'green',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This will also return t-shirts that have the `sleeve = green` meta field - I only want to see dress-shirts that have a green sleeve OR t-shirts that have the `heal = green` meta field

Comment: Then remove t-shirts post type from post_type array.

Comment: I want to see both combinations on one page with pagination: t-shirts that have the `heal = green` meta field & dress-shirts that have the `sleeve = green` meta field - not other combinations

Answer (score 0):

You also can create two arrays for each of your post types and put your wp_query loop inside of a function which gets argument , so anywhere you want to use that is enough to call your loop function and give it an array of argument for each post type.

function wp_loop($args){

$post = new WP_Query($args);

while($post->have_posts()): $post->the_post();

```
 ...
```

endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
}

now for each post type we do as follow:
$args = array(
'post_type'=>'t-shirts',
...
);
wp_loop($args);

And for the next post type (dress-shirts) we work the same:
$args = array(
'post_type'=>'dress-shirts',
...
);
wp_loop($args);

Comment: How exactly will I manage pagination with two separate queries?